# How to loop through an array of objects and calculate yearly revenue for each year and display it in a table using Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular and looking for some answers on how to get this done.
I am using Angular 2.

I am trying to calculate yearly revenue of the given response object.
So I am making and http request to get data back from an API. Below is the response body:

```
{
 "accountName": "SHELL TRADING SERVICES CO",
 "wbsList": [
{
  "wbsId": "W1MLR",
  "monthlyFindata": [
    {
      "year": "2016",
      "month": "Jan",
      "quarter": "Q1",
      "revenue": "16988.09",
      "cost": "15049.85",
      "gp": ""
    },
    {
      "year": "2017",
      "month": "Jan",
      "quarter": "Q1",
      "revenue": "0.00",
      "cost": "0.00",
      "gp": ""
    },
    {
      "year": "2016",
      "month": "Apr",
      "quarter": "Q2",
      "revenue": "13567.20",
      "cost": "9158.94",
      "gp": ""
    },
    {
      "year": "2017",
      "month": "Apr",
      "quarter": "Q2",
      "revenue": "0.00",
      "cost": "0.00",
      "gp": ""
    },
  ],
  "quarterlyFindata": [
    {
      "year": "2016",
      "quarter": "1Q",
      "revenue": "57845.24",
      "cost": "47308.82",
      "gp": "",
      "gpPercentage": "0.182148436068"
    },
```

I need to loop through the data and calculate the yearly revenue for each year ex. 2016, 2017, 2018, etc. Then get the result and display it in a table. I know that it is my logic in the table.component.ts is wrong.

Below is a snippet of my files I am working with:

table.component.html

```
<div class="bs-component">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>GP%</th>
    <th>QP</th>
    <th>Rev</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr class="active">
    <td></td>
    <td>Column content</td>
    <td>Column content</td>
    <td>Column content</td>
    <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
```

finsummary.service.ts

```
postFinSummary(){
    let body = {
    "accountName": "SHELL TRADING SERVICES CO",
    "currentYear": "2017",
    "wbsList": [
        "W1MLR"
        ]
}

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Content-Type');

let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this._http.post(this._url, body, options)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
 }
```

table.component.ts

```
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {
    showTables: boolean;
    wbsArray =[];
    q1RevDatavArray = [];
    currentYear = '2017';
    previousYear = '2016';
    q1Rev: number = 0;
    q2Rev: number;
    q4Rev: number;

    constructor(private _finSummaryService: FinsummaryService, ){
        this._finSummaryService.postFinSummary().subscribe(
        wbssList => {
            console.log(wbssList);

            for(var i=0; i<wbssList.wbsList.length; i++) {
            this.wbsArray[this.wbsArray.length] = wbssList.wbsList[i].wbsId;
            for(var z=0; z<wbssList.wbsList[i].monthlyFindata.length; z++){
            let sum = 0;
            if(wbssList.wbsList[i].monthlyFindata.year == this.currentYear && 
                wbssList.wbsList[i].monthlyFindata.qaurter == '1Q' ) {
                this.q1RevDatavArray[this.q1RevDatavArray.length] = w 
                bssList.wbsList[i].monthlyFindata.rev;
                sum += this.q1RevDatavArray[i];
                console.log(sum);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for arrays

```js
this.yearStats = this.data.reduce((stats, month) => {
  if (!stats[month.year]) {
    stats[month.year] = { revenue: 0, cost: 0 }
  }
  stats[month.year].revenue = stats[month.year].revenue + parseFloat(month.revenue)
  stats[month.year].cost = stats[month.year].cost + parseFloat(month.cost)
  return stats;
}, {})
```

And display it in a table with interpolation

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Revenue</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let year of years">
    <td>{{year}}</td>
    <td>{{yearStats[year].revenue}}</td>
    <td>{{yearStats[year].cost}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mqWlb4UqKwCyjbK5YMH5?p=preview)